# ros_controllers problems

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,
I am writing a description of my robot combining xacros, gazebos and yamls files. I have some troubles with my controllers and sensors.

About sensors:
I am tring to add an IMU in my robot. I have a link "imu_link" in my xacro and a fixed joint "imu_joint" between imu_link and another link in my robot. Now, in my robot.gazebo file I have the following:

> imu_link
>     1
>     1000.0
>     /COMAN
>     coman_imu

and in my robot_control.yaml I have:

> imu_sensor_controller:
>     type: imu_sensor_controller/ImuSensorController
>     publish_rate: 50

In the launch file for the controller I use the controller_manager spawner to spawn the imu_sensor_controller. When I launch it I have the following error from GAZEBO:

> [ERROR] [1380671129.134196839]: This controller requires a hardware interface of type 'hardware_interface::ImuSensorInterface'. Make sure this is registered in the hardware_interface::RobotHW class.

I think I have to put this in my transmission.urdf.xacro but I do not well know where is he syntax for the imu hardware interface. Do you have some suggestion? Maybe I am wronging something?

Thank you for your help.

Enrico

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4569/ros_controllers-problems/) by [Enrico Mingo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/507/enrico-mingo/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 121 on 2013-10-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Solved using the following:

```
 <gazebo>
    <plugin name="quadrotor_imu_sim" filename="libhector_gazebo_ros_imu.so">
      <updateRate>100.0</updateRate>
      <bodyName>imu_link</bodyName>
      <topicName>COMAN/raw_imu</topicName>
      <rpyOffsets>0 0 0</rpyOffsets> <!-- deprecated -->
      <gaussianNoise>0</gaussianNoise>  <!-- deprecated -->
      <accelDrift>0.5 0.5 0.5</accelDrift>
      <accelGaussianNoise>0.35 0.35 0.3</accelGaussianNoise>
      <rateDrift>0.1 0.1 0.1</rateDrift>
      <rateGaussianNoise>0.05 0.05 0.015</rateGaussianNoise>
      <headingDrift>0.1</headingDrift>
      <headingGaussianNoise>0.05</headingGaussianNoise>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>
</robot>
```

---

Originally posted by [Enrico Mingo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/507/enrico-mingo/) with karma: 121 on 2013-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [psei](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/464/psei/) on 2013-10-10**:
Does this IMU plugin simulate realistic data? I tried to simulate my IMU with "libgazebo_ros_imu.so", but the simulated data doesnt look very good....

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-10-10**:
Can you start a new question, and elaborate on "doesn't look very good"?

**Comment by [psei](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/464/psei/) on 2013-10-14**:
Hello nkoenig, see http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4717/imu-sensor-plugin-libgazebo_ros_imuso-strange-data/